# How does $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(t) + i \widetilde f(t))^{2k}\ dt = 0\ $?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

> Let $f$ be a real-valued trigonometric polynomial on $\mathbb T$ with $\hat f (0) = 0.$ Let $\widetilde f$ be the Hilbert transform or the conjugate transform of $f.$ Then $\widetilde f$ is also real-valued and hence $(f + i \widetilde f)$ only contains all the positive frequencies. Therefore,
>
> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(t) + i \widetilde f(t))^{2k}\ dt = 0$$ for any $k \in \mathbb N.$

This has been claimed in the book *Classical Fourier Anslysis* by Grafakos. Could anyone please shed some light on how does the integral being zero follow from the fact that the integrand has only positive Fourier coefficients? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your valuable time.

**EDIT** $:$ The integrand can be easily seen to be $2^{2k} \left (\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \hat f (n) e^{int} \right )^{2k}.$ I think it is zero because $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{im t}\ dt = 0$ for any $m \in \mathbb N.$ But then it should be true for any odd powers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a trig polynomial $\phi(t) = \sum_{m} a_m e^{2\pi imt}$ with only positive frequencies. Note this does **not** mean that the coefficients $a_m$ are positive, but rather that $a_m = 0$ if $m\le 0$ (in other words, "positive" refers to the index $m$). Since $\phi(t)$ is a trig polynomial with only positive frequencies, $a_m = 0$ if $m \le 0$ or if $m > M$ for some large enough positive $M$.

As you noted, $\phi(t)^n$ can be expanded out for any $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, and we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb T}\phi(t)^n\,dt = \sum_{m_1,\dots,m_n=1}^Ma_{m_1}\dots a_{m_n}\int_{\mathbb T} e^{i(m_1+\dots+m_n)t}\,dt = 0,
$$
the last equality holding because $m_1+\dots+m_n\ge n >0$ is a nonzero integer.

I think there may be a separate reason for choosing $2k$ (rather than arbitrary $n$) in the proof, possibly owing to the organization of the proof. The fact itself does not rely on $2k$ being even.

Comment: $:$ I am very much aware of what I meant by positive Fourier coefficients. I meant Fourier coefficients corresponding to positive indices only survive i.e. those Fourier coèfficients corresponding to negative integers are all zero. But I really don't understand the reason of taking even powers in the integrand. This seems misleading to me.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa: I think the motivation for taking $2k$ is ultimately a separate question. It doesn't have to do with the integral $\int \phi(t)^{2k}\,dt$ being zero, as I showed. You could try leaving it as an unspecified $n$ and mimic the rest of the proof. You could check if any step of the proof that follows is seriously affected if we don't take $n = 2k$.

Comment: Should I ask it as a separate question then?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa: Yes, making a new question for a separate question is the site standard. My guess for why the even powers are being used comes in what follows in the proof after this line.

Comment: You mean taking real parts of the integrand would be easier? We just need to consider even index terms of the binomial expansion and that would work. Another reason might be that the even powers of a real-valued function are all non-negative. So we can get rid of the absolute value in the integrand when considering its $L^1$-norm. Later the author used Hölder's inequality and that's possibly one of the reasons to make the integrand non-negative by considering its even powers.